# Set package path in "Execute Package Task" From Integration Service Catalog in SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I would like to call SSIS package dynamically based on the configuration of various packages. I have deployed SSIS 2012 solution on Integration Service Catalog.

At run time I am having the the package name but unable to set the path of SSIS package from Integration Catalog. I am able to do this from file location but as I am using 2012 so need to use Integration Service.

Comment: I think this link can help you [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have to use Expressions to achieve this.

### Example

*Assuming that:*

1. The packages are located in the following Catalog:

   ```
   MSDB\MyPackages\Import\
   ```
2. The Package Name is stored in the variable `@[User::Variable]`

**Solution**

First of all, create an `OLEDB Connection manager` to connect to the SQL Server instance related to the Integration Services Catalog.

Add the Execute Package Task and configure it To run package from SQL Server , and use the connection you have created.

[image]

On the `Execute Package Task` *(just click on the task and press F4 to show properties Tab)* go to Expressions.

Set The Package name Expression To:

```
"\\MyPackages\\Import\\" + @[User::Variable]
```

[image]

*Side Note: I assumed that all package are stored in `MSDB\MyPackages\Import\` otherwise you have to store the full path inside the variable*